# @media width component

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to create a CSS Rule so the div ".ise" is hidden only when window size is lower than 980px. I **cannot** create an inverse function so it shows when (min-width: 980px). I created this rule but it doesn't works I would really appreciate your help.

```
@media(max-width:980px){
  .ise{
     display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is correct and works properly.
`@media` works with window size. thus when you resize your browser window, its width changes.
debug the window width with this code:

```
<a onclick="alert($(window).width());">hi</a>
```

try it in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dariushvb2010/J5AaG/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `LESS`, a dynamic language for **styling the document**.
and You can use javascript in it.
or if you dont want to use `LESS`, see [this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#width)

Comment: This is not what I'm looking there for. Can you please READ carefully the question? ``"..a CSS Rule.."`` and the link you gave me didn't help at all.